# <p> not aligning itself in center of container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

,  and  are all inside one container. I've used align-items-center to align them all in the same line inside the container. However that property is not applying to the

tag. What am I missing? I want "or" to be aligned with the sign up and log in button.

```css
nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#login{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: max-content;
    max-height: min-content;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav>
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between ">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="container-flex d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="#" style="white-space: nowrap">Sign up</a>
                    <p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em;"> or </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="login">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: <p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em; margin-bottom:0;">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 paragraphs `<p>` have a bottom margin. Use the `mb-0` class to remove it.

```
<p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em;" class="my-0"> or </p>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/n337ATFcOh

---

You could simplify the markup and CSS a lot by utilizing the [Bootstrap Navbar or Nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/). There is also no reason to use [nested containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers).

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZiTM3iuHrd

Answer (score 1):

You have a margin set to p element. Just remove it and you are good to go:

```css
nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#login{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: max-content;
    max-height: min-content;
    margin: 0;
}

nav p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav>
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between ">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="container-flex d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="#" style="white-space: nowrap">Sign up</a>
                    <p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em;"> or </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="login">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you also use margin-bottom:0

or

Answer (score 1):

```css
.mb-0{margin-bottom:0px;}
```

```html
<p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em;" class="mb-0"> or </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

add margin-top in p tag as below:

```css
 nav ul{
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav li{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 0.2em;
    }
    nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #login{
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: max-content;
        max-height: min-content;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav>
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between ">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="container-flex d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="#" style="white-space: nowrap">Sign up</a>
                    <p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em; margin-top: 15px;"> or </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="login">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are not really explanations as to why this is happening.

All tags have default styling in the browser. You can look at them here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp.

So the `<p>` has default styling of `margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;`. To remove it set the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `0`. You can do this with the class `my-0`.

```
lesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav>
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between ">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="container-flex d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="#" style="white-space: nowrap">Sign up</a>
                    <p style="padding-right: 0.5em; padding-left: 0.5em;" class="my-0"> or </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="login">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```